# randomForest same formula different results (with same seed!)

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using randomForest function with same seeds, but gives different results.
(with Boston dataset)

```
set.seed=500
regressor = randomForest(x = training_set,
                          y = training_set$medv,
                          ntree = 100)

Call:
 randomForest(x = training_set, y = training_set$medv, ntree = 100) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 100
No. of variables tried at each split: 4
      Mean of squared residuals: 0.03206772
                % Var explained: 96.78
```

OR :

```
set.seed=500
  regressor =randomForest(medv ~ . , data = training_set,ntree=100) 

Call:
 randomForest(formula = medv ~ ., data = training_set, ntree = 100) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 100
No. of variables tried at each split: 4
      Mean of squared residuals: 0.1248719
                % Var explained: 87.48
```

Gives different call results.
Any helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set.seed=500` initializes a variable called `set.seed` and sets it to 500. It does not set the random number generator seed.

Use `set.seed(500)` instead.

You can look at the help page by `?set.seed`.

---

In addition, note that your first model (`x = training_set`) includes *all* columns of the training data set - including the dependent variable `medv`. In contrast, the second one (`medv ~ .`) tells R to exclude the DV from the IVs. Of course these will give different results, since the training data are different.

Below, I give a reproducible example. The last model is an adaptation of your first model, and it indeed gives the same results as your second one.

```
library(randomForest)
library(MASS)
training_set <- Boston

set.seed(500)
regressor = randomForest(x = training_set,
                          y = training_set$medv,
                          ntree = 100)
regressor

set.seed(500)
regressor =randomForest(medv ~ . , data = training_set,ntree=100) 
regressor

set.seed(500)
regressor = randomForest(x = training_set[,-14],
                          y = training_set$medv,
                          ntree = 100)
regressor
```

---

Finally, note that you will typically get better help if you include a minimal reproducible example like the one I gave here.

Comment: I tried like you said set.seed(500) . anyway it is the same... nothing changed..

Comment: Then please edit your post to include a reproducible example, i.e., one that runs in a fresh R console.

Comment: I am trying to understand if it differs because of format difference  one is: randomForest(x = training_set,y = training_set$medv, ntree = 100)    other is: randomForest(formula = medv ~ ., data = training_set, ntree = 100)    in theory these are the same, but results differ?

Comment: thank you so much, your addition answer was the one I looked for. the problem is exclusion, thought the code was doing it auto (cause we show the target as Y) thanks!! also I am taking your suggestion about the reproducible example.